# DateRangePicker - combine range selection with dynamic presets

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using the [DataRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) JS library in my form for selecting a range of two dates. DRP offers the function of placing a button with a dropdown menu of pre-defined dates such as Yesterday, Today, Last Month, etc., but I would like to have this as combined with the original dropdown window when clicking on the date input field.

DPR does offer a settings generator that can do this (in a way), but only allows for static dates to be set. I have since used the moment() functions to change those to dynamic ranges for the button, but cannot manage to combine the JS into one function. What am I doing wrong here?

HTML

```
  <!-- Date and time range -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date and time range:</label>

    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterangepicker" id="daterangepicker" />
    </div>
    <!-- /.input group -->

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="daterange-btn" id="daterange-btn" />
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date range picker
        </span>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>

  </div>
  <!-- /.form group -->
```

JS for input field (working)

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterangepicker"]').daterangepicker({
        alwaysShowCalendars: true,
        showWeekNumbers: true,
        timePicker: true,
        timePicker24Hour: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 30,
        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'
        }
    });
```

JS for button (working)

```
$('input[name="daterange-btn"]').daterangepicker(
    {
      ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      },
      startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
      endDate: moment()
    },
    function (start, end) {
      $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }
)
```

Combined JS for input field (not working)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Date range picker with time picker
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="daterangepicker"]').daterangepicker({
            alwaysShowCalendars: true,
            showWeekNumbers: true,
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            timePickerIncrement: 30,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'
            },

            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
              },
              startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
              endDate: moment()
            },

            function (start, end) {
              $('#daterangepicker').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
            }
        )                           
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: not working at all or?

Comment: Not working at all, DPR is not giving any response which normally means theres a typo (which there isnt).

Comment: You have no response due to it was jQuery/JavaScript typo which caused the jQuery/JavaScript totally not working.. Error only given if the jQuery is working but can't find the element or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had miss some bracket and wrong place bracket

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Date range picker with time picker
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="daterangepicker"]').daterangepicker({
            alwaysShowCalendars: true,
            showWeekNumbers: true,
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            timePickerIncrement: 30,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'
            },
            { // here
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                  },
                  startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
                  endDate: moment()
            },

            function (start, end) {
              $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
            }                           
    });
}); // here
    </script>
```

Comment: sigh, time for bed, no sense coding anymore... Thanks a lot!

Comment: :) kindly click the Tick if you find this answer is correct.. Thanks :)

Comment: strange, I adjusted the code, placed the right brackets, but still am not getting any response...? Nothing in the chrome console either

Comment: nevermind, I will figure it out another day, this answer helped me plenty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

turns out the DRP syntax is treating the "ranges" object in a special way and does not require brackets. 
thanks @AKZhang who pointed out the missing brackets though.

The following code worked for me:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Date range picker with time picker
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="daterangepicker"]').daterangepicker({
            alwaysShowCalendars: true,
            showWeekNumbers: true,
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: true,
            timePickerIncrement: 30,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            },
            startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
            endDate: moment(),

            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'
            },

            function (start, end) {
              $('#daterangepicker').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
            } 
        });
    }); // here
    </script>
```